# Maximum Likelihood with Uniform and Normal Distributions

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

I am having a bunch of trouble figuring out the likelihood function for this problem.

Let $\eta \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ and $\epsilon \sim U(-A,A)$ independently, and $K,P_1,P_2$ are constants :

Define:

$ f(\theta)=  \left\{ \begin{array}  a \theta P_1 + \eta & \text{ if  } \theta P_1 + \eta\leq K-A \\
                                       \theta P_2 + \eta & \text{ if  } \theta P_1 + \eta> K-A \\
                                        \end{array} \right\} + \epsilon$

Through convolution of the uniform and normal distributions, I've been able to figure out that the unconditional probability of observing $f(\theta)$ is (where $i$ indexes $P$):

$Convo(i) = \frac{1}{2 A}\big[\Phi(\frac{f(\theta) - \theta P_i + A}{\sigma}) - \Phi(\frac{f(\theta) - \theta P_i - A}{\sigma})\big]$

The next step that I'm having trouble with is figuring out how to deal with the different cases.  It seems to make sense to me to divide $f(\theta)$ into regions that are associated with only first part of the piecewise function (below $K-2A$), both parts of the piecewise function (between $K-2A$ and $K$), and then the last part of the piecewise function (above $K$).  In each of these segments, I figured I'd multiply the unconditional probability of each $f(\theta)$ with the probability that $\eta$ results in observations in this range.  Here's what I've been working with so far but it doesn't seem right based on the simulations; any tips would be very much appreciated!

$L(\theta) = \Pi_{j=1}^{n} \Big[  \Phi( \frac{K-2A-\theta P_1}{\sigma})      Convo(1) \Big]^{ \mathbb{1}\{f(\theta)\leq K-2A\} }    \Big[ \Big(\Phi( \frac{K-A-\theta P_1}{\sigma}) -  \Phi( \frac{K-2A-\theta P_1}{\sigma}) \Big)     Convo(1) +  \Big(\Phi( \frac{K+A-\theta P_2}{\sigma}) -  \Phi( \frac{K-A-\theta P_1}{\sigma}) \Big)     Convo(2) \Big]^{ \mathbb{1}\{f(\theta)>K-2A \hspace{.2cm}  \& \hspace{.2cm} f(\theta)\leq K  \} }  \Big[  (1- \Phi( \frac{K-A-\theta P_1}{\sigma}))      Convo(2) \Big]^{ \mathbb{1}\{f(\theta)>K\} }      $